# python/flask/Jinja2 and Json

Tags: python, json, highcharts, flask, jinja2

"I am using Flask,Jinja2,higHighcharts"

Example (Python/Flask):

```
@app.route("/column/")
def column():
    data=[{"data": [49.9, 54.4], "name": "Tokyo"}, {"data": [42, 30.4], "name": "AC"}]
    return render_template('column.html', data=data)
```

my templates

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
         },
         title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
         },
         xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
         },
         yAxis: {
            title: {
               text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
         },
         series:{{ data }}
      });
   });
```

i view highcharts (column.html)

```
series:[{&\#39;data': [4, 5, 9], &\#39;name&\#39;: &\#39;Jane&\#39;},{&\#39;data&\#39;: [8, 3, 4], &\#39;name&\#39;: &\#39;John&\#39;}]});
```

i want to correct Jinja2 wording,Ultimately the desired results.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]}, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
         }]
```

Comment: @Blender Thank you, this is what I want.change {{ data }} to {{ data|tojson|safe }}.

Comment: Would you mind posting your full column.html file (with the javascript), I am working on the same problem and I can't get your code to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Mark your data as *safe* with [`Markup`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Markup):

> Marks a string as being safe for inclusion in HTML/XML output without needing to be escaped.

Or change `{{ data }}` to `{{ data|tojson|safe }}`.

Comment: Or just change `{{ data }}` to `{{ data|tojson|safe }}`.

Comment: It seems that in Flask 0.10 you no longer need to mark the string as 'safe' with the `tojson` filter. Ie. `{{ data|tojson }}` should work fine [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-filters)