# chart.js with flask not displaying values

Tags: javascript, python, charts, jinja2

I am trying to create a line graph using chart.js and getting the data from jinja2 template schema.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

  [{% for data in graph.data.all() %}{{data.int_data}},{% endfor %}]
  [{% for data in graph.data.all() %}"{{data.time}}",{% endfor %}]
  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var Data = {
    labels :  [{% for data in graph.data.all() %}"{{data.time}}",{% endfor %}],
    datasets : [
    {
    fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
    strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
    pointColor : "#fff",
    pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
    data : [{% for data in graph.data.all() %}{{data.int_data}},{% endfor %}]
    }]
    }
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(Data);
  </script>
</div>
```

I can see the data on the webpage but the graph doesn't show up.  If I put in made up data lists into labels and data in the data set it works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the 2 lines for above the `<script>` tag?

Comment: Those are for debugging to know that I was able to get the correct values which do output the correct values into a list.

Comment: maybe this is the answer to your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168539/python-flask-jinja2-and-json

Comment: No luck there, added the changes but still didn't work